# ActiveRecord joins syntax

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, outer-join

I need to express the following join condition using ActiveRecord:

```
SELECT ...
FROM U
LEFT OUTER JOIN F ON U.key = F.foreign_key
 AND F.key = ?
WHERE ...
```

where ? is substituted at run time.

The following causes a SQL-syntax error:

```
joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN F on U.key = F.foreign_key AND F.key=?", key)
```

I can't seem to determine if ActiveRecord supports this 'dynamic substitution' (whatever this is called).

Adding the restriction (where("F.key=?", key)) in the WHERE clause will collapse the OUTER JOIN to a JOIN.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This syntax worked:

```
joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN F on U.key = F.foreign_key AND F.key=#{key}")
```